# Are Asynchronous Byzantine Fault Tolerance and Partition Tolerance mutually exclusive?

Tags: consensus, algorithm

Within the IOTA network specifically, has partition tolerance been prioritised over aBFT? If so, why?

Comment: *IOTA has partition tolerance been prioritised over aBFT* - I'm curios, what is the source of this statement? I'm a newbie in IOTA protocol, but the way you state it, this doesn't seem to be a well-know fact.

Comment: I havent seen any claims that IOTA is fault tolerant, which seems to be a problem for data integrity. The only explanation I can think of is that it’s incompatible with partition tolerance.

Comment: I think this question should be bumped to the front page.

Comment: Currently, with coo, IOTA network is aBFT (and not so partition tolerant). So I guess that you are asking this in the context of a Tangle with something like a decentralized coordinator. Can you clarify the question ? Can you also add links to your claims or at least explain your reasonning ?